# XSL to XML loop problem

Tags: xml, xslt

I need to loop a XML document. No problem there.
The problem come when I need text from  the previous line I have just skipped.

The XML will look some thing like this

```xml
<lines>
  <line>
    <id>1</id>
    <text>Some fancy text here 1</text>
  </line>
  <line>
    <id></id>
    <text>This I need in the next line with a ID</text>
  </line>
  <line>
    <id></id>
    <text>Also need this.</text>
  </line>
  <line>
    <id>4</id>
    <text>Here we go</text>
  </line>
</lines>
```

The output XML file need to look like this

```xml
<output>
  <line>
    <id>1</id>
    <note>Some fancy text here 1</note>
  </line>
  <line>
    <id>4</id>
    <note>Here we go</note>
    <extra>
      <note>This I need in the next line with a ID</note>
      <note>Also need this.</note>
    </extra>
  </line>
</output>
```

The XSL I have so fare is simple to sort out the line that have no ID set.

```xml
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <output>
    <xsl:for-each select="lines/line">
      <xsl:if test="id/text() &gt; 0">
        <line>
          <id>
            <xsl:value-of select="id" />
          </id>
          <note>
            <xsl:value-of select="text" />
          </note>
        </line>
      </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
    </output>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: An `xsl:for-each` is **not** a loop. It's a function assignment for each match of your `select`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not resist to completely review your code :)

Here follows a complete XSLT 1.0 solution more functional-oriented (no procedural approach). It might look at first seen harder to see, but, imho, it's a very good example to get started into XSLT templating mechanism.

Also using `xsl:for-each` in your specific case is not that easy, because at a certain step of the loop you want to get all preceding adjacent siblings with empty `id`, without knowing how many they are *a priori*.

I've also used the *identity template* to simplify the work of recreating your target.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <!-- identity template -->
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- match line with empty id and do not output -->
    <xsl:template match="line[not(boolean(id/text()))]"/>

    <!-- match line with id and build output -->
    <xsl:template match="line[boolean(id/text())]">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:copy-of select="id"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="text"/>
            <extra>
                <!-- apply recursive template to the first preceding 
                sibling adajacent node with empty id -->
                <xsl:apply-templates select="(preceding-sibling::*[1])
                    [name()='line' and not(boolean(id/text()))]/text" 
                    mode="extra"/>
            </extra>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- change text element to note --> 
    <xsl:template match="text">
        <note>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </note>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- recursive template for extra note elements -->
    <xsl:template match="text" mode="extra">
        <note>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </note>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="(parent::line/preceding-sibling::*[1])
            [name()='line' and not(boolean(id/text()))]/text" 
            mode="extra"/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Applied on your input, gives:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<lines>
   <line>
      <id>1</id>
      <note>Some fancy text here 1</note>
      <extra/>
   </line>
   <line>
      <id>4</id>
      <note>Here we go</note>
      <extra>
         <note>Also need this.</note>
         <note>This I need in the next line with a ID</note>
      </extra>
   </line>
</lines>
```

Comment: This works great.    Thow I might have maken some haste on the first ekasmple, as I might have some more after id 4. There can bee sevel line with number after eatch other that all need to have the same two line added to the extra field.    I will pussel with it.     Thanks again

Answer (score 2):

You need to select the preceding-sibling;  there is an [example here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/XML/XSLT-stylesheet/precedingsibling.htm).

Basically the xpath syntax for you would be something like (not tested):

```
preceding-sibling::NodeName[1]
```

Comment: That xpath is going to get the first prceding-sibling (of what??). It seems that the OP needs all preceding adjacent siblings. Is not that clear also how to apply this to the current use case.